# Handling sizes for iPhone 5, 6, and 6 Plus for height and widths (points)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, dimensions, points

I have the following code in a view controller:

```
UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 35.0, 310.0, 90.0)];

[self addSubview:text];
```

If the iPhone width has changed from 5 to 6 to 6 Plus, why does the above code look fine when I run it in all those simulators?

I thought the widths were:

```
iPhone 5: 320
iPhone 6: 375
iPhone 6 Plus: 414
```

The views look fine in all the simulators but shouldn't they be shorter in the iphone 6 and 6 plus?

Comment: you defined the fixed width and height so why should it be shorten?

Comment: because the width of the phones is different sizes

Answer (score 1):

**iphone sizes :**

**iphone 4/4s:**

320 X 480

**iphone 5:**

320 X 568

**iphone 6:**

375 X 667

**iphone 6 plus:**

414 X 736

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) // iPhone and       iPod touch style UI

#define IS_IPHONE_5_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS7 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height < 568.0f)

#define IS_IPHONE_5_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) == 736.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS8 (IS_IPHONE && ([[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height/[[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale]) < 568.0f)

#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_5_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_5_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_6 ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_6_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_6_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_6P ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_6P_IOS7 )
#define IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER ( ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] respondsToSelector: @selector( nativeBounds ) ] ) ? IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS8 : IS_IPHONE_4_AND_OLDER_IOS7 )
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: these are new size changes for apple new devices iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus

Comment: I have updated my answer on the behalf of these new sizes new macro that i found, that's work for me dnt know that also works for your scenario, hope that's work you :)

Comment: but this is not an answer to the question, read his problem, which is also misleading as I found out

Comment: hm ok, so what would be the answer of his question ?

Comment: I think the best aswer for his question is using Autolayout (Any H Any W). what would you say @julian Krol ?

Comment: he has some problem with sizing components (which in my opinion is not well specified, could be mixing auto layout and or autoresizing masks and or fixed size components) but it is definitely not problem of detection device on which his code is running

Comment: nope and I gave up as he is missing the explanation.